# Intermittent error "There was an error while attempting to compile the stylesheet"

Tags: saxon

We're using Saxon-EE 9.9.1.6 in our project. Until June it was working fine, but starting from that time many of our customers have encountered with the following error when trying to execute a priori valid xslt file:

```
   System.NullReferenceException details:
    Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    Source : saxon9ee
    Method : net.sf.saxon.expr.Expression bind(F, net.sf.saxon.expr.Expression[], net.sf.saxon.expr.StaticContext, java.util.List)
    Stack  :    at net.sf.saxon.functions.FunctionLibraryList.bind(F functionName, Expression[] staticArgs, StaticContext env, List reasons)
   at net.sf.saxon.functions.FunctionLibraryList.bind(F functionName, Expression[] staticArgs, StaticContext env, List reasons)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseFunctionCall(Expression prefixArgument)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseBasicStep(Boolean firstInPattern)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseStepExpression(Boolean firstInPattern)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseRelativePath()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parsePathExpression()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseSimpleMappingExpression()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseUnaryExpression()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseExprSingle()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseFunctionArgument()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseFunctionCall(Expression prefixArgument)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseBasicStep(Boolean firstInPattern)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseStepExpression(Boolean firstInPattern)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseRelativePath()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parsePathExpression()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseSimpleMappingExpression()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseUnaryExpression()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseExprSingle()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseFunctionArgument()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseFunctionCall(Expression prefixArgument)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseBasicStep(Boolean firstInPattern)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseStepExpression(Boolean firstInPattern)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseRelativePath()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parsePathExpression()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseSimpleMappingExpression()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseUnaryExpression()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseExprSingle()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseExpression()
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parse(String expression, Int32 start, Int32 terminator, StaticContext env)
   at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionTool.make(String expression, StaticContext env, Int32 start, Int32 terminator, CodeInjector codeInjector)
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.makeExpression(String expression, Int32 attIndex)
   at net.sf.saxon.style.XSLValueOf.prepareAttributes()
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.processAttributes()
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.processAllAttributes()
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.lambda$processAllAttributes$1(NodeInfo )
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.__<>Anon1.accept(Item )
   at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.<default>forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator , ItemConsumer )
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.processAllAttributes()
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.lambda$processAllAttributes$1(NodeInfo )
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.__<>Anon1.accept(Item )
   at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.<default>forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator , ItemConsumer )
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.processAllAttributes()
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.lambda$processAllAttributes$1(NodeInfo )
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.__<>Anon1.accept(Item )
   at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.<default>forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator , ItemConsumer )
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.processAllAttributes()
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.lambda$processAllAttributes$1(NodeInfo )
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.__<>Anon1.accept(Item )
   at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.<default>forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator , ItemConsumer )
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.processAllAttributes()
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.lambda$processAllAttributes$1(NodeInfo )
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.__<>Anon1.accept(Item )
   at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.<default>forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator , ItemConsumer )
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.processAllAttributes()
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.lambda$processAllAttributes$1(NodeInfo )
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.__<>Anon1.accept(Item )
   at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.<default>forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator , ItemConsumer )
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.processAllAttributes()
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.lambda$processAllAttributes$1(NodeInfo )
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.__<>Anon1.accept(Item )
   at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.<default>forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator , ItemConsumer )
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.processAllAttributes()
   at net.sf.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.processAllAttributes()
   at net.sf.saxon.style.PrincipalStylesheetModule.processAllAttributes()
   at net.sf.saxon.style.PrincipalStylesheetModule.preprocess()
   at net.sf.saxon.style.Compilation.compilePackage(Source source)
   at net.sf.saxon.style.StylesheetModule.loadStylesheet(Source styleSource, Compilation compilation)
   at net.sf.saxon.style.Compilation.compileSingletonPackage(Configuration config, CompilerInfo compilerInfo, Source source)
   at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler.compile(Source source)
   at Saxon.Api.XsltCompiler.Compile(TextReader input)
   at EDG.SaxonWrapper.XsltParser.CreateExecutable(FileInfo stylesheet)
```

Does anybody encountered with such behavior too and have ideas how to avoid it?

I suppose it can be related to some kind of Windows/Antivirus updates, but I can't reproduce it locally and I can't do much on customer's prod environments. Or it can be related to Saxon 9.9 release, because we never encountered with such issue on Saxon 9.7.

P.S. Our colleagues from similar project were getting almost the same error:

```
DocGen Result Exception. Response is invalid: Request is failed. Response body: {"message":"Error generating document (7cf581ac-2287-4396-bca4-0d5c5af9c308). Error: null (java.lang.NullPointerException)\n Stack Trace: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.saxon.functions.FunctionLibraryList.bind(FunctionLibraryList.java:124)
    at net.sf.saxon.functions.FunctionLibraryList.bind(FunctionLibraryList.java:124)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseFunctionCall(XPathParser.java:3356)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseBasicStep(XPathParser.java:2206)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseStepExpression(XPathParser.java:2076)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseRelativePath(XPathParser.java:2000)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parsePathExpression(XPathParser.java:1957)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseSimpleMappingExpression(XPathParser.java:1971)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseUnaryExpression(XPathParser.java:1824)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseExprSingle(XPathParser.java:753)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseFunctionArgument(XPathParser.java:3552)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseFunctionCall(XPathParser.java:3322)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseBasicStep(XPathParser.java:2206)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseStepExpression(XPathParser.java:2076)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseRelativePath(XPathParser.java:1995)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parsePathExpression(XPathParser.java:1957)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseSimpleMappingExpression(XPathParser.java:1971)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseUnaryExpression(XPathParser.java:1824)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseExprSingle(XPathParser.java:753)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseExpression(XPathParser.java:660)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parse(XPathParser.java:522)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.ExpressionTool.make(ExpressionTool.java:107)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.makeExpression(StyleElement.java:735)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.XSLValueOf.prepareAttributes(XSLValueOf.java:51)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.processAttributes(StyleElement.java:618)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.processAllAttributes(StyleElement.java:551)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.lambda$processAllAttributes$1(StyleElement.java:554)
    at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator.java:128)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.processAllAttributes(StyleElement.java:552)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.lambda$processAllAttributes$1(StyleElement.java:554)
    at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator.java:128)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.processAllAttributes(StyleElement.java:552)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.lambda$processAllAttributes$1(StyleElement.java:554)
    at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator.java:128)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.processAllAttributes(StyleElement.java:552)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.lambda$processAllAttributes$1(StyleElement.java:554)
    at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator.java:128)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.processAllAttributes(StyleElement.java:552)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.lambda$processAllAttributes$1(StyleElement.java:554)
    at net.sf.saxon.om.SequenceIterator.forEachOrFail(SequenceIterator.java:128)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StyleElement.processAllAttributes(StyleElement.java:552)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.XSLTemplate.processAllAttributes(XSLTemplate.java:427)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.PrincipalStylesheetModule.processAllAttributes(PrincipalStylesheetModule.java:583)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.PrincipalStylesheetModule.preprocess(PrincipalStylesheetModule.java:367)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.Compilation.compilePackage(Compilation.java:287)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.StylesheetModule.loadStylesheet(StylesheetModule.java:223)
    at net.sf.saxon.style.Compilation.compileSingletonPackage(Compilation.java:107)
    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler.compile(XsltCompiler.java:788)
    at com.tr.e3etdocgen.SaxonWrapper.getTemplate(SaxonWrapper.java:232)
    at com.tr.e3etdocgen.SaxonWrapper.lambda$initTemplates$0(SaxonWrapper.java:177)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:290)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:401)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:734)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:159)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:650)
    at com.tr.e3etdocgen.SaxonWrapper.initTemplates(SaxonWrapper.java:174)
    at com.tr.e3etdocgen.SaxonWrapper.transform(SaxonWrapper.java:126)
    at com.tr.e3etdocgen.Function.run(Function.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodInvokeInfo.invoke(JavaMethodInvokeInfo.java:22)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodExecutorImpl.execute(JavaMethodExecutorImpl.java:54)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:57)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:92)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 (java.lang.NullPointerException)","status":"error"},
 status: InternalServerError
```

Comment: Can you get a stack trace from the customers? Also note that as an EE customer you can contact Saxonica's support at https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/issues or via email.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the message "There was an error while attempting to compile the stylesheet" is produced by your application if the call on compile() throws an exception. You're welcome to raise this directly with Saxonica support, but we will need more detailed diagnostics than this.

One possibility, if you are running many stylesheet compilations (which your post suggests might be the case) is that you are hitting a JVM limit with the number of classes that can be compiled using bytecode generation. Switching bytecode generation off would probably be a good idea in that kind of scenario.

**UPDATE** (2021-10-31): A bug report was raised at https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5148 and has been resolved.

Comment: You're right. I missed that our service uses a wrapper to operate with Saxon and mentioned error is produced by the wrapper (together with Saxon-generated errors).

Unfortunately, the application doesn't extract AggregateException in proper way, as a result we have no possibility to see what is happened exactly. 

So, before reaching to Saxon support we need to improve our application to see real error messages. 

Thank you again!

Comment: And interesting hint with bytecode generation. We had some changes recently with bytecode generation approach, probably it is related.

Comment: I have a question regarding mentioned bytecode generation issue. As I see https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/1833 has been closed with resolution "no longer an active issue".  Did you meant another issue?

Comment: We took a number of actions over the years to address the issue identified in 1833: we allowed more selective control over bytecode generation, we introduced hotspot bytecode generation, we introduced a static (i.e. JVM-wide) limit on the amount of bytecode generated, and at the same time the JVM's memory management improved. That doesn't mean that no-one was ever going to hit problems again, just that we felt the problem was now manageable.

Comment: Hi Michael, we've updated our error handling and were able to catch this intermittent error on Saxon side. Also we got some additional information definitely related to the same error from our colleagues.

I've updated original post. Could you please take a look?

Unfortunately I can't provide sources because it contain customer's information and I can't simplify them. Moreover, the error is very intermittent and I have no strong way to reproduce it. I just hope that probably you saw something similar and know something about that.

Comment: Btw, forgot to mention: we've disabled byte-code generation completely, but the error still occurs.

Comment: The second stack trace is more useful because it contains line numbers. FunctionLibraryList.java:124 is a debug line tracing the process of binding function calls, the line should only be executed if option `TRACE_EXTERNAL_FUNCTIONS` is true. So it might be some kind of secondary error. However, let me say again that to solve this kind of problem we need to be able to reproduce it. Please raise a bug report by the proper channels and construct a repro that we can investigate. We want to see this solved and it's frustrating not to have the information we need to help you.